# SQLAlchemy dynamic & customized Collection Class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following SQLAlchemy model :

```
from datetime import date

from app import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Date
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Article(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'article'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)

    posts = relationship('Post', back_populates='article')


class Post(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'post'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    article_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('article.id'))
    date = Column(Date)

    article = relationship('Article', back_populates='posts')
```

What I would like is having a fast and flexible way to get the posts of an article `article` between a date `start_date` and a date `end_date`.

I know that I could do:

```
`session.query(Post).filter(Post.article == article, Post.date >= start_date, Post.date < end_date).all()`
```

but I find it too long and not 'Object-Oriented' enough.

After some research, I saw that I could use the `lazy` argument of `relationship`:

```
posts = relationship('Post', back_populates='article', lazy='dynamic')
```

After that, the "posts" attribute isn't a list any longer, but a Query Object, which allows us to do:

```
article.posts.filter(Post.date >= start_date, Post.date < end_date).all()
```

But what I would like to do would be:

```
article.posts[start_date:end_date]
```

I think I have to use the `collection_class` attribute, for instance :

```
class DatedList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, slice):
            # What to do here ?
        else:
            super(DatedList, self).__getitem__(item)

posts = relationship('Post', back_populates='article', lazy='dynamic', collection_class=DatedList)
```

But I don't know what to write inside the `__getitem__` function, because we don't have access to the query given by the `relationship` Object !

Does someone have an idea which could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by posting on the SQLAlchemy Google Group.

As said by Mike Baker, the `collection_class` doesn't work with the `lazy` argument set at `dynamic`, so I had to use the `query_class` argument:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query


class PostClassQuery(Query):

    def __getitem__(self, item):

        if isinstance(item, slice) and (isinstance(item.start, date) or isinstance(item.stop, date)):
            query = self
            if isinstance(item.start, date):
                query = query.filter(Post.date >= item.start)
            if isinstance(item.stop, date):
                query = query.filter(Post.date < item.stop)
            return query.all()
        else:
            super(PostClassQuery, self).__getitem__(item)
```

and after in the Article entity:

```
posts = relationship('Post', back_populates='article', lazy='dynamic', query_class=PostClassQuery)
```

If you want, you can even return a Query instead of the result, by removing `.all()` in `return.query.all()`, which would allow you to do something like `article.posts[date(2015, 1, 1):date(2015, 6, 1)][10:20]`.